# How to do ? serious skewed right transformations normally distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution

My target is doing two-way Anova. But Here is some problem.
This is my data like
[image]
I try log(X). Looks like a normal distribution. But try Kolmogorov-Smirnov prove is not.
[image]
Can anyone recommend another way to transform?

Comment: What exactly is $X?$ ANOVA makes no assumption about the target variable, just the residuals (error term, technically).

Comment: please explain your data types and variable what is the objective/hypothesis?